# Understanding a proof : infinite prime numbers $p\equiv 1 \pmod4.$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Today, in exam, a purpose a an exercise was to prove that there exist an infinite prime numbers  $p\equiv 1 \pmod4.$

First question it was to prove that $f:(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^*\to(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^*\quad x\mapsto x^2$ was an homomorphism and to find  the kernel, second question to find the cardinal of Im$(f)$ which is $\frac{p-1}{2}.$ Then it was to prove that $$\mbox{Im}(f)=\{y\in (\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^*: y^{(p-1)/2}=1\}.$$

After it was to prove that $-1$ is a square in $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^*$  if and only if $p\equiv 1 \pmod4.$

Finally the last question was to prove that to prove that there exist an infinite prime numbers  $p\equiv 1 \pmod4.$

> *For this one, I was stuck.* Seeing previous question I said that equivalently is to prove that $-1$ is a square in $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})^*$ infinitely often, as Im$(f)$ is the numbers of square, perhaps that the equation $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}=1$ has infinitely many solutions, which I think it's pretty easy to 'see'.

**Question:** What I miss? Is there a trick? Or, perhaps, I am thinking correctly for my last thoughts?

Comment: Hint: $M^2+1$ is only divisible by primes $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and possibly $2$, by your previous parts. Now given finitely many $p_i\equiv 1\pmod 4$, pick $M$ so that $M$ so that $M^2+1$ is not divisible by any $p_i$ or $2$. (Think of Euclid's prove of infinitely many primes.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Nice hint, I got it. Too bad that I didn't find it by myself..and thanks